# Unity 3D workflow - Constantly rebuilding lighting

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

A team of us have been working in Unity for the last 6 months using Git for source control (I know it might not be the recommended method).

Every time we pull a new commit from Git, we have to rebuild the lighting (or if 'auto' is selected in the lighting preferences Unity will auto re-build the lighting once the scene has been opened).

Should this happen? Re baking all the lighting takes ages and is a real pain if we have to go through it every time a new commit is pulled? Shouldn't the full lighting data be being stored on git along with the baked lighting files and preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below lighting settings when working on the game other than lighting.

Lighting >> Precomputed Realtime GI >> Realtime Resolution >> 0.2f (Or less)

Default value is 2f.

Downsize atlas from default 1024.

Lighting >> General GI >> Atlas size >> 512. (Or less)

Turn off Ambient Occlusion.

Lighting >> baked GI >> Ambient Occlusion >> 0.

These will not look good but you can work as ease at speed. Bake a better lightmap when have time.